# C#: Passing enum type as argument

Tags: c#, enums, c#-2.0

I tried to convert enum to a generic List by using the following code

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(Type t) where T : struct
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

it complied successfully.

and I tried to call the above mentioned method by using the following code

```
 enum Fruit
    {
        apple = 1,
        orange = 2,
        banana = 3
    };

    private List<Fruit> GetFruitList()
    {
        List<Fruit> allFruits = EnumHelper.ToList(Fruit);
        return allFruits;
    }
```

resulted in the following error

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0118: 'default.Fruit' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
```

So I am sure how to pass Enum type as a argument.

Comment: StackOverflowException found it first, you need to reference typeof(Fruit) rather than Fruit when calling EnumHelper.ToList(Type)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>() where T : struct
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToList();
}

enum Fruit
{
    apple = 1,
    orange = 2,
    banana = 3
};

private List<Fruit> GetFruitList()
{
    List<Fruit> allFruits = EnumHelper.ToList<Fruit>();
    return allFruits;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. I already tried that one. but my question is still there how to pass Enum Type as argument.

Answer (score 4):

why not just do this:

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>()
{     
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToList(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Fruit> allFruits = EnumHelper.ToList<Fruit>(typeof(Fruit));
```

Answer (score 1):

Loose the argument `Type t`

The type is already being passed as generic parameter, so you don't need a regular argument for the method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `EnumHelper.ToList<Fruit>(typeof(Fruit));`. However, you can lose the parameter, declare as `EnumHelper.ToList<T>()` and use it `EnumHelper.ToList<Fruit>()`.

Comment: The first option is wrong: this actually will result in an error of "*cannot infer type arguments for EnumHelper.ToList*"

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass a `Type` to your function, you should use the following syntax:

```
 EnumHelper.ToList(typeof(Fruit));
```

Comment: Wrong answer: this actually will result in an error of "*cannot infer type arguments for EnumHelper.ToList*"

Comment: I wanted to show how to pass a type as a parameter, I shouldn't have used his own method since, you're right, there would be a problem with the generic argument.